# Sometimes my listBox1 or the value im updating inside is blinking for second or less how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code I'm updating the `ListBox`:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => data = new List<string>()));
this.Invoke(new Action(() => data.Add("Gpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = null));
this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = data));
this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Invalidate()));
```

The variable data is `List<string>` once I added a new for the data so now the value of sensor(sensor.Value) is updating on the place i mean the old value each time deleted and a new one is added.

Sometimes the item itself in the `ListBox` blinking for less then a second or so and sometimes only the `sensor.Value` is blinking.

Tried to add a `Validate()` for the `ListBox` didn't help.

This is the background do work event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    while (true)
    {

        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
            {
                soundPlay = true;
                blinking_label();
                NudgeMe();
            }
            else
            {
                soundPlay = false;
                stop_alarm = true;

            }
            cpuView();
            gpuView();
        }
    }
}
```

I have two more events of the listBox:

```
private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = 25;
}

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index == -1)
    {
    }
    else
    {

        ColorText.ColorListBox(data, e);

    }
}
```

And the ColorText function from another class wich color the items in the listBox:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    class ColorText
    {


        public static void Texts(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }

        public static void ColorListBox(List<string> data, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            string strLeft = null;
            string strMid = "---";
            string strRight = null;
            if (data[e.Index].Contains(strMid))
            {
                int index = data[e.Index].IndexOf(strMid);
                strLeft = data[e.Index].Substring(0, index);
                strRight = data[e.Index].Substring(index + strMid.Length);
            }

            using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 20, FontStyle.Regular))
            {
                float startPos;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strLeft, f, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
                startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft, f).Width;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strMid, f, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
                startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strLeft + strMid, f).Width;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(strRight, f, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds.X + startPos, e.Bounds.Y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i make the `ListBox` so it will not blinking each few seconds or every time a new sensor.Value value is updated ? I,m not sure why and when exactly it happen but the `ListBox` item and the sensor.Value are blinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from the fact that you're clearing the `DataSource` and then setting it again.  It shouldn't be necessary to set the data source to `null` and then reset it when the data changes.

Try removing these two lines and see if the flickering goes away:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = null));
this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `Invoke` method is wrong and that could be the reason for the blinking.

Try to change the first section of your code like this:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        data = new List<string>();
        data.Add("Gpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString());
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.DataSource = data;
        listBox1.Invalidate()
    }));
```

Every time you call the `Invoke` method, a message is posted to the application's message queue, and later is processed in the UI thread when UI is not busy. By calling `Invoke` multiple times, you send multiple messages, that will be processed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Once I solved putting this on my form:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```